# How to automatically answer user prompts in Java?

Tags: java, linux, bash, parameter-passing, prompt

I'm using a compiled Java file which takes a filename as a parameter and then asks for a username and password (via user input).  I am trying to automate this from a shell script, but am running into problems.  I'm unable to access the java code, which is why I am having trouble.
   So the code is called the following way

```
java javaprogram /home/user/securityfile
```

So, you pass the file, and then it asks you for username and password.  After entering those, it's done.

Now, I have tried to put the user input into a file and pass it in, but I get an error.

```
java javaprogram /home/user/securityfile < userinputfile
```

userinput file contains the following text (First line is the username, second line is the password):

```
MattSmith
MSpassword136
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  Maybe I am doing it wrong?

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at ilex.util.UserAuthFile.main(UserAuthFile.java:297)
```

Thanks

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: "I get an error" is never an adequate description of a problem.

Comment: How are you normally prompted by program? What is in `userinputfile`? How do you expect us to help you without providing us with relevant information?

Comment: @shmosel, I'm sorry if I posted a non-programming question.  I thought bash scripting is programming, but if I posted incorrectly, I can delete the question...

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask. *"Unix and Linux Stack Exchange is for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un\*x-like operating systems. If your question is about: [...] Shell scripting [...] then you're in the right place."*

Comment: Is there a newline after the password?

Comment: No, there is not a newline after the password, but I have tried it both ways (2 lines with no new line as well as 3 lines with the last line being a newline).  Same results both times.

Comment: @Andreas ok, thanks I can ask it there.  Thanks for the help and sorry about the nuisance everyone.

Comment: If you just want to figure out what the Java program is doing, perhaps try decompiling it? Or, since it sounds like this is a Linux system, you could try using `strace` to see exactly how it's interacting with the console. Note that any mechanism to read a password securely on the console won't work with a pipe; you'll probably need a pty instead.

Comment: maybe answers there will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695444/how-to-pass-a-file-as-stdin-in-a-shell-script I'm not sure but try first this: `java javaprogram /home/user/securityfile 0<userinputfile`. Still it highly depends on how user input accepted inside `javaprogram` code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i am looking through the strace right now.  I did try adding a 0 before the "<", but that didn't fix it.  I will continue to look into this.

Comment: Try `(echo "user"; sleep 1; echo "password") | java javaprogram /home/user/securityfile`. If that works you can refactor to read from file without too much work.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz That is a good thought, unfortunately I am getting the same error.  :(  Thanks for the thought though...I'm keeping at it! :)

Comment: May be that app will never read from `System.in` since it requires an interactive console `System.console()`. Some info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html).

Comment: See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637349/pass-multiple-lines-of-stdin-input-to-interactive-java-command-line-program-non).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
`(echo "user"; sleep 1; echo "password") | java javaprogram /home/user/securityfile`

If that works you can refactor to read from file without too much work. If it doesn't, may be that app will never read from `System.in` since it requires an interactive console `System.console()`. Some info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html).

Comment: You were spot on, I was doomed from the beginning.  System.console() is what it is using.  Thanks for the help.